# Database inner join update

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to update a table column from a table column in another table and am using the following code - it generates the error below.

Any ideas?

```
UPDATE URLRecord
```

SET URLRecord.Slug = aaNewURLSlugss.NewSlugName
    FROM URLRecord 
    INNER JOIN aaNewURLSlugs ON URLRecord.Slug = aaNewURLSlugss.OldSlugName

Error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near ','.

Comment: There is no comma in the code.  So, that makes this particularly error message highly unlikely.

Comment: Check above and below your statement.... maybe that comma is lurking from code you commented out, or didn't fully delete.

Comment: try putting some nonsense statement before and after update like `select 'before update'` and `select 'after update'` this should let us know if the problem is somewhere else. If you are running in *management studio*, open new query and run update statement there.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server doesn't like the qualified column name in `SET`.  Does this work?

```
UPDATE r
  SET Slug = n.NewSlugName
FROM URLRecord r inner join
     aaNewURLSlugs n
     ON r.Slug = n.OldSlugName;
```

The error message would be different, though, from what you are getting.  This would be an additional error.

Comment: @MichaelJ.Gray . . . The "SELECT" was a typo, and I addressed the OP's issue in a comment.

Comment: @MichaelJ.Gray . . . Your comment is about a typo in the original answer.  The word "SELECT" should have been and is now "SET".

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working solution that uses a temporary table. It may not be ideal and I've included some drop statements, so don't run this on your production machine.

```
-- Build our test tables
CREATE TABLE [URLRecord]
(
    [Id] INTEGER IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    [Slug] CHARACTER VARYING(255) NOT NULL
)

GO

CREATE TABLE [NewSlugs]
(
    [Id] INTEGER IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    [NewSlugName] CHARACTER VARYING(255) NULL,
    [OldSlugName] CHARACTER VARYING(255) NULL
)

GO

-- Insert test data
INSERT INTO [URLRecord] VALUES ('Original Name');
INSERT INTO [NewSlugs] VALUES ('New Name', 'Original Name');

-- Populate work table with the records we want to modify
SELECT [URLRecord].[Id], [NewSlugs].[NewSlugName] INTO #SlugWork
FROM [URLRecord]
INNER JOIN [NewSlugs] ON [URLRecord].[Slug] = [NewSlugs].[OldSlugName]

-- We're just echoing here
SELECT * FROM #SlugWork

-- Pull everything from our temporary table and update modified records
UPDATE [URLRecord]
SET [URLRecord].[Slug] = [T].[NewSlugName]
FROM #SlugWork AS [T]
WHERE [T].[Id] = [URLRecord].[Id]

-- Proving it's updated
SELECT * FROM [URLRecord]

-- Drop our example stuff, for rerunnability
DROP TABLE #SlugWork
DROP TABLE [NewSlugs]
DROP TABLE [URLRecord]
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to use embedded sql like this:

```
UPDATE URLRecord
  SET Slug = (
     SELECT NewSlugName 
     FROM aaNewURLSlugs 
     WHERE URLRecord.Slug = aaNewURLSlugs.OldSlugName )
WHERE Slug IN (SELECT OldSlugName FROM aaNewURLSlugs)
```

Comment: This will update every single row in `URLRecord` to the same value.

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: Either it does or it doesn't. I suggest you test it yourself @quantummind and use those learnings for future postings.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid It doesn't. I only wanted to be polite. Why should I try it? It's clear.

Comment: I tried it myself and _does_ update every row. The `WHERE` clause doesn't do what you think it does. In SQL Server anyway. Just saying there's no 'think so' in programming... it either does or it doesn't. I hope this isn't taken the wrong way - nothing personal!

Comment: Oh, I see. You have understood "update every single row" and missed "to the same value". Yes, sure, the lines I've posted contained only the idea, that's why I've written "like". It works only with 1-1 relationship in that form. No, problem, of course nothing personal, I know you only want to help, and so do I.

Comment: So... it was edited after my comment and _now_ it will not update every row. :/

Comment: Yes, I've put a WHERE clause at the end of the statement, so it works now not only in case of 1-1 relation. I've also corrected a typo which came from the question. That was made to please you. Without that last line it works only with 1-1 relationship, as I've written to you. In that case it updates every row, but not to the same value. Please withdraw your downvote.

Answer (score -1):

Try using Aliases

```
UPDATE A
SET A.Slug = B.NewSlugName
FROM URLRecord AS A 
INNER JOIN aaNewURLSlugs B
ON A.Slug = B.OldSlugName
```

Comment: Surprising that this gets upvotes, because it doesn't work.

Comment: Why would aliases change anything?